# Single text box search in ng-table

Tags: angularjs, search, ngtable

I am using `ng-table` for users listing in my app.

[image]

This is my table, I can single field a time. But I want to search multiple keys with single field

I have a array of values `var search = ['Suhail', 'User'];`
I want to search this array in data

Eg:- Suhail,User Like

```
function getUsers(params) {
        var data = { page: params.page(), count: params.count() };
        if (!users.length) {
            var getUsersCallBack = userService.getUsers(data);
            return getUsersCallBack.then(function (response) {
                var responseJson = angular.fromJson(response.data);
                vm.out = responseJson.data;
                users = vm.out.invitations.concat(vm.out.users);
                users.forEach(function (user, index) {
                    user.statusName = status[user.status];
                    user.invitation = (index < vm.out.invitations.length) ? "Pending" : "Accepted";
                    user.roleName = vm.userRoles[user.role];
                }, this);
                vm.tableBasic.total(users.length);
                var orderedData = vm.search ? $filter('filter')(users, vm.search) : users;
                vm.resultNotFound = orderedData.length ? false : true;
                return (orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            });
        }
        else {
            var searchArr = vm.search.$.split(";");
            var orderedData = vm.search ? $filter('filter')(users, vm.search) : users;
            vm.resultNotFound = orderedData.length ? false : true;
            vm.tableBasic.total(orderedData.length);
            return (orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }

    }

    vm.tableBasic = new NgTableParams({
        page: 1,
        count: 5
    }, {
            counts: [],
            filterDelay: 300,
            getData: getUsers
        });
```

Comment: can you put your code here?

Comment: @Dixit updateed

Comment: Why you doesn't search in array? If you have data in array (to display it in rows by ng-repeat) you can search in whole JSON instead one field.

Comment: I want to search like User,Active @kris_IV

Answer (score 1):

Just use in-build $filter of angular. 
You have object with all table data. Apply angular filter on that variable and then show the response in table.

```
$scope.loadTable = function(){
        $scope.data = $scope.searchText ? $filter('filter')($scope.table_data, $scope.searchText) : $scope.table_data;
        $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({},{dataset: $scope.data});
    }

    $scope.clearSearch = function(){
        $scope.searchText = '';
        $scope.loadTable();
    }
```

Here **loadTable** function is called on submitting **Search button** and **clearTable** function is called on clearing the filter and reloading the table data.